# laravel : how can i update multiple rows in one time?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I want to select multiple rows in update them in one time by changing 1 attribute for all of them ,
I have no idea how can I do it , guys if you have a tutorial or video who explain it, share it with me !

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, something like this should suffice in your controller function:

```php
DB::table('Contact List')
              ->where('id', '<=', $high_end)
              ->where('id', '>=', $low_end)
              ->update([
                      'First Name' => 'Sultan',
                      'Last Name' => 'Soleman',
                       ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your controller function

```
ModelName::whereIn("id",$idArr)->update([Ref' => 'By Google']);
```

$idArr is array of requested userId.

Answer (score 0):

Example  ModelName=Person

Controller

```
use App\Models\Person;      
Person::query()->update(['column_name' => 'value']);
```

Or View

```
@php
 use App\Models\Person;      
 Person::query()->update(['column_name' => 'value']);
@endphp
```

This codes update to all rows.If you're just update selected columns on controller method.Call method in foreach funtion with POST

you must define it at the top of the page Request class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
public function person_update(Request $request)
{
        $person_update= Person::find($request->ID);
        $person_update->Ref= $request->ref;
        $person_update->first_name= $request->first_name;
        $person_update->another_column_name= $request->another_value;
        $person_update->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is my working code. you may want to try this.

This is my datatable checkbox code. I'm using yajra datatable. so this is coded in my controller.

```
<label class="checkbox checkbox-single">
   <input name="users[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $user->id . '" class="checkable">
   <span></span>
</label>
```

This button in html will handle bulk edit

```
<button class="btn  btn-danger disabledeleted mr-2" id="bulkupdate" onclick="updateRecords()">Update</button>
```

The javascript function being called on clicking button.

```
function updateRecords(){
    var ids = [];
    $('[name="users[]"]:checked').each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
         url: $url, // route to bulk edit handler method in controller
         type: 'post',
         data: {
            "id": ids,
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
         },
         success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            // execute your operations after success
         },
     });    
}
```

This is my controller function to handle bulk edit

```
public function updateUser($id) {
    $query = new User();
    $updateData = [
        'active' => 1,
        'deleted_at' => null
    ];
    if(is_array($id)) {
        $query = $query->whereIn("id", $id);
    } else {
        $query = $query->where("id", $id);
    }
    if($query->update($updateData)){
        return Response::json([
            "status" => true,
            "msg" => 'success',
        ]);
    }else{
        return Response::json([
            "status" => false,
            "msg" => 'update failed',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you @imane